# Updating 0 vector values based on preceding and successive values

Tags: r, sequence

I have a data frame which has a cumulative count for each event (an event in this case being represented by a sequence of 1's in the bin column) with separating values given the value 0 and each event given an ID as such:

```
  bin cumul  ID
   0     0   0
   1     1   3
   1     1   3
   1     1   3
   1     1   3
   0     0   0
   0     0   0
   0     0   0
   0     0   0
   1     2   2
   1     2   2
   1     2   2
   1     2   2
   1     2   2
   0     0   0
   0     0   0
   0     0   0
   0     0   0
   1     3   1
   1     3   1
   1     3   1
```

I want to update the ID column so each non-event (0 in the bin column) is assigned an ID value based on the previous and subsequent ID.

Therefore, if a non-event is preceded and succeeded by events of equal ID values (e.g. both 3) the non-event also carries this ID value (3). However if the non-event is preceded by an event with one value but succeeded with an event with a different value then the first half of the non-event is given an ID value equal to the preceding event and the final half of the non-event is given an ID value equal to the ID value of the succeeding event. Giving the final data frame:

```
 bin  cumul ID
   0     0   3
   1     1   3
   1     1   3
   1     1   3
   1     1   3
   0     0   3
   0     0   3
   0     0   2
   0     0   2
   1     2   2
   1     2   2
   1     2   2
   1     2   2
   1     2   2
   0     0   2
   0     0   2
   0     0   1
   0     0   1
   1     3   1
   1     3   1
   1     3   1
```

Comment: Can there be an uneven number of non-events? What to do then?

Comment: Yes there are occurrences of non even events. In this case I want to assign to the previous event's ID value.

Comment: @JojoOno I don't think you read that question very carefully. If the sequence is 1,0,0,0,3 then what is desired value for the middle-0?

Comment: And is there a limit to the number of consecutive non-events?

Comment: Apologies - what I meant to say was in this case I want to assign the middle non-event the ID value of the preceding event.

Comment: @docendo discimus - there is no limit to the number of consecutive non-events but it does vary.

Answer (score 2):

If the question were how to fill in the zeros with ID that matched the preceding values, or matched successive values, then you could use `na.locf` from the zoo-package and it would be a one liner. For this task I think you might reach for the `rle` function:

```
rle(dat$ID)
#Run Length Encoding
#  lengths: int [1:6] 1 4 4 5 4 3
#  values : int [1:6] 0 3 0 2 0 1
```

Then thinking about how to use such result, my thinking was to use an algorithm like:

```
for each '0' in values; assign the first [`length`/2 + .9] values as $values[ idx-1 ]
                       assign the next ]`length`/2] values as $values[ idx+1 ]
            ( using `rep` will truncate/floor the fractional indices and adding a number 
               slightly less than 1.0 will take care of the edge cases where there are an 
                odd number of zeros in a row.)
             ( `sum` on the lengths can recover the correct positions.)
  and for the beginning and ending 0-cases;
              replace with successive and preceding values respectively
```

After considerable debugging effort (and commenting out the debugging `cat`-calls):

```
rldat <- rle(dat$ID)
for ( nth in seq_along( rldat$lengths) ){  #cat("nth=", nth, "\n")
     if(rldat$values[nth] == 0){ 
             if (nth == 1) { # cat("first value=",rldat$values[nth+1], "\n")
                      dat$ID[ 1:rldat$lengths[nth] ] <-rldat$values[nth+1]; 
                                     } else {
                if (nth== length(rldat$lengths) ){ 
                   dat$ID[  (length(dat$ID)-rldat$lengths[nth]+1):length(dat$ID) ]  <- 
                       rldat$values[nth-1]
                } else {
      # cat( "seq=", (sum(rldat$lengths[1:(nth- 1)])+1): sum(rldat$lengths[1:nth]) ,"\n")
                dat$ID[ (sum(rldat$lengths[1:(nth-1)])+1):sum(rldat$lengths[1:nth]) ] <-
                       c( rep( rldat$values[nth-1],rldat$lengths[nth]/2+.9) , 
                          rep( rldat$values[nth+1],rldat$lengths[nth]/2) )}}
 } }
```

Comment: This is just the ticket, @42-. Thank you very much for you effort.